# Cant access to pages on my site

Tags: php, .htaccess

My problem is that when I try to access the some file, for example
http://domain.com/myFile.php?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2
Sometimes it works, and sometimes it redirects me to:
https://domain.commyfile.php/?Key1=Value1&Key2=Value2
this problem started after I added TLS to the site (redirecting http to https works fine, But this problem showed up).

my .htaccess file:

```
        # Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain$1 [R,L] 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

can anyone tell me why does it happen?

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/$1 [R,L] try that

Comment: Something is missing in the question. What are the lines after "RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on" ?

Comment: There are no lines after that... That is the all file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the RewriteRule because the base is `/`. Do the following:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain/$1 [R,L] 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed it yesterday, So far it fixed the problem!
Thanks!